# Vue JS set first item in a populated select to be selected with v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have tricky challenge with vuejs, I want to have two select fields. the first one should select fruits for example, and the second should list all fruits. If I select vegetable from the first select field, the second select field should list all vegetable.

I stumble and find similar stuff online but I don't know how to make first item in the second select field selected.

anytime I select fruits, the first item on the list in second select first should be selected as default, and if I select vegetable, the first item in the second select field should be selected as default.

pls help me check the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/aj6g87dh/1/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    category: 'fruits',
    list: '',
    optionsData: {
       fruits: [
            { text: 'Orange', value: 'orange' },
            { text: 'Banane', value: 'banana' },
       ],
       
       vegetables: [
           { text: 'Brocolis', value: 'brocolis' },
           { text: 'Radish', value: 'radish' },
       ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    options: function() {
      let options = ''

      switch (this.category) {
        case 'fruits':
          options = this.optionsData.fruits
          break;

        case 'vegetables':
          options = this.optionsData.vegetables
          break;

        default:
          options = this.optionsData.fruits
      }

      return options
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onChange: function() {
      this.options = this.options
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.5/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <select v-model="category" v-on:change="onChange" id="select1">
    <option value="fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>

  </select>

  <select id="select2" v-model="list">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value"> {{ option.text }} </option>
  </select>

  <span>{{  }}</span>

</div>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove onChange method and add a watch property. This way you can handle changing logic there.

Also, you can simplify options retrieval to one line.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    category: 'fruits',
    list: '',
    optionsData: {
      fruits: [{
          text: 'Orange',
          value: 'orange'
        },
        {
          text: 'Banane',
          value: 'banana'
        },
      ],

      vegetables: [{
          text: 'Brocolis',
          value: 'brocolis'
        },
        {
          text: 'Radish',
          value: 'radish'
        },
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    options: function() {
      return this.optionsData[this.category]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    category: {
      handler: function(newVal) {
        this.list = this.optionsData[newVal][0].value;
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">

  <select v-model="category" id="select1">
    <option value="fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>

  </select>

  <select id="select2" v-model="list">
    <option v-for="(option, i) in options" v-bind:value="option.value"> {{ option.text }} </option>
  </select>

  <span>{{ }}</span>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but when I first load the page I should have Orange, as a default selected field.  This is how I implemented it but I know if there is a way to improve it. `mounted() {  var groupSelect = this.$refs.groupSelect.children;`
     ` if (groupSelect.length) {`
       ` this.list = groupSelect[0].value;`
       
     ` } } `  Then I use this <select class="control" v-model="list" ref="groupSelect"></select>

Comment: You can add `immediate` property to watch to make it work when the page loads for the first time. I updated my answer.